# HTTPClient redirect when using POST method

Tags: java, post, redirect, httpclient

I have a site that redirect me to another site with this php code:

```
<?php
    header("Location: new.php?id=".$_POST["id"]."&test=".rand(5,15));
    echo "35";
?>
```

-new.php

```
<?php
    echo "ID: ".$_GET["id"]."| TEST: ".$_GET["test"];
?>
```

If I try to send a Post request with the HTTPClient, the site doesn't redirects me to the other site (response of the post request is 35). It works perfectly fine when I send a Get request. the response of the request is ID: | TEST: 13.

-http.java

```
public class Http {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpResponse response;
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost/test.php");
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id","55"));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response = client.execute(post);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://localhost/test.php");
            response = client.execute(get);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automatically redirecting POST requests is against RFC standards. Therefor, the HttpClient will not do this by default. However, according to the API of the [DefaultRedirectStrategy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRedirectStrategy.html) this can be achieved by using the [LaxRedirectStrategy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/LaxRedirectStrategy.html).

In code this would look something like:

```
  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  httpClient.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy());
  httpClient.execute(request);
```